# Preventing the execution of the previous function when closing the modal bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

I defined a function for when a modal is closed. I use the following codes for this:

```
<div id="myModal" tabindex="-2" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


$("#myModal").modal('hide')
$("#myModal").on("hidden.bs.modal", closeModal)
function closeModal(){
    console.log('my modal')
}
```

When I close the medal for the first time the function executes correctly. But after the first execution and when I want to close the modal in another function, the closeModal run again. I want the closeModal to not be executed when I close the medal in other codes. like this.

```
function showModal(){
    $("#myModal").modal('show')
    $("#myModal").modal('hide') // this line run closeModal again. i dont want to run closeModal here
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Add some flag that indicates if modal is closed from `showModal` or not